# Sprite bounding box size after addChild

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I create a sprite without using an image like this:

```
    auto sprite = Sprite::create();
sprite->addChile(label1);
sprite->addChile(sprite1);
sprite->addChile(sprite2);
sprite->addChile(label2);
```

After all this I want to get resulting bounding box size. But `sprite->getBoundingBox().size` returns `(0, 0)`. Why? And how to get final size?

Answer (score 0):

`addChild` method do not change any of sprite properties therefore sprite having no texture will always return (0,0) unless you have changed it using `setContentSize` method.

Comment: There is no automatic calculation of current size? Cause I can add things, remove, move, but always want to get the bounding box.

Comment: You can create your custom class which inherit sprite class and then you need to override addChild method and in that you can calculate for bounding by finding min x, max x, min y, max y,

Comment: Yes, it is always possible :). So I guess it is not supported in cocos2d-x 3.